бот не отправляет Update при нажатии на кнопку телеграм
Пишу бота для изучения слов и хотел добавить кнопки под сообщение со словом, но при нажатии на кнопку не происходит ничего: в метод onUpdateReceived ничего не попадает, т.к. я все вывожу, телеграмм делает вид, что грузит что-то, но не похоже, ошибки не выдает.
Пробовал уже с VPN, т.к. видел, что проблема может быть в РКН. Все остальное работает корректно

public class Botik extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        String chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId().toString();

        deleteMsg(chatId, update.getMessage().getMessageId());

        System.out.println(update);
        if (update.hasMessage()){
            ...
        }
        else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
            System.out.println("callback");
            System.out.println(update.getCallbackQuery().getData());
            if (update.getCallbackQuery().getData().equals("know")) {
                System.out.println("good");
            }
            sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().toString());
        }

    }

    public SendMessage getWordMessage(String chatId, String[] word) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setText(word[1]);

        InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();

        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowsInline = new ArrayList<>();

        List<InlineKeyboardButton> rowInline1 = new ArrayList<>();

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton1 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        inlineKeyboardButton1.setText("Know");
        inlineKeyboardButton1.setCallbackData("know");

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton2 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        inlineKeyboardButton2.setText("Don't know");
        inlineKeyboardButton2.setUrl("https://www.google.com/");

       
        rowInline1.add(inlineKeyboardButton1);
        rowInline1.add(inlineKeyboardButton2);
        rowsInline.add(rowInline1);

        markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
        sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);

        return sendMessage;
    }
}

